# Set dynamic string data of different languages to textview in android

Tags: android, rss-reader

In my android application i am parsing RSS feeds. The feeds language is not unique. I am displaying the feed items in a list view using adapter. How to set text of different languages to a textview inside listview. I dont want to change app language. I only need textview to support multiple languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Typeface` to achieve this.

Go through this link [Typeface](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_custom_fonts.htm) and you'll get a good idea how to use it in your application.

Download the otf/ttf file of the language you want to set and place it in the assets folder.
Then you need to do this to set the text:

```
Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"myLanguage.ttf");
myTextView.setTypeface(myTypeface);
```